# global command in exec not substituting the values

Tags: python, global-variables

```
import re
def test ( var ):
    op=""" 
    1/1/1/1  up        up :99005      53476      99005      g993-2-17a  
    1/1/1/2  up        up :99005      53148      99005      g993-2-17a  
    1/1/1/3  up        up :99005      53793      99005      g993-2-17a  
    """
    op=op.splitlines()
    for line in op:
        pattern = "([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+) *?([a-z]+) *?([a-z]+) :([0-9]+) +?([0-9]+) +?([0-9]+) +?([a-z0-9-]+)"
        if re.search(pattern, line):
            match=re.search(pattern, line)
            var1=re.sub(r'/', '_', match.group(1))
            x = var+"_"+ var1
            print x
            if_index = match.group(1)
            adm_state = match.group(2)
            exec("global %s" % (x))
            exec("%s = {}" % (x))
            exec("%s['whole']=match.group(0)" % (x))
            exec("%s['if_index']=match.group(1)" % (x))
            exec("%s['adm_state']=match.group(2)" % (x))
            exec("%s['opr_state']=match.group(3)" % (x))
            exec("%s['tx_rate_us']=match.group(5)" % (x))
            exec("%s['tx_rate_ds']=match.group(6)" % (x))
            exec("%s['op_mode']=match.group(7)" % (x))
            print info_1_1_1_1['if_index']


test("info")
print info_1_1_1_1
```

Hi everyone am new to python and scripting. The above one is my    script and my aim is creating multiple dictionary and assigning key    and value pair for the corresponding dictionary. For each line i    wanted to create separate dictionary. And i wanted to to the    dictionary with the same name from global space. If anything not    clear let me correct it.

In global space i wanted to access dictionary like info_1_1_1_1['whole']

---

Answer (score 1):

`global` doesn't persist between two `exec` invocations. This would work:

```
exec("global bar\nbar=3\n")
```

But dynamic setting of variables is a strong code smell. Every time you find yourself doing something similar to this, you should immediately stop and reevaluate if there is another way to do this. In this case, I suggest using a dictionary instead:

```
import re
data = {}
def test ( var ):
    op=""" 
    1/1/1/1  up        up :99005      53476      99005      g993-2-17a  
    1/1/1/2  up        up :99005      53148      99005      g993-2-17a  
    1/1/1/3  up        up :99005      53793      99005      g993-2-17a  
    """
    op=op.splitlines()
    for line in op:
        pattern = "([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+) *?([a-z]+) *?([a-z]+) :([0-9]+) +?([0-9]+) +?([0-9]+) +?([a-z0-9-]+)"
        if re.search(pattern, line):
            match=re.search(pattern, line)
            var1=re.sub(r'/', '_', match.group(1))
            x = var+"_"+ var1
            print(x)
            data[x] = {
                "whole": match.group(0),
                "if_index": match.group(1),
                "adm_state": match.group(2),
                "opr_state": match.group(3),
                "tx_rate_us": match.group(5),
                "tx_rate_ds": match.group(6),
                "op_mode": match.group(7),
            }
            print(data["info_1_1_1_1"]['if_index'])

test("info")
print(data["info_1_1_1_1"])
```